# How to turn random jsonb in postgres into kv table

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a json as a field.
The structure of a json is completly random but it never has inner objects inside.

| data |
| --- |
| {"test": "baa-1496", "test2": "baa-1431", "test3": "baa-1497"} |
| {"test": "baa-1452", "test4": "baa-1597"} |

i want to turn this table into this

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| test | "baa-1496", "baa-1452" |
| test2 | "baa-1431" |
| test3 | "baa-1497" |
| test4 | "baa-1597" |

where each value from each json is spliced into different row
and values with same keys united in one row as array

json probably isn't the best option for this, but we need it for other purposes

does anybody know, how to achive this by any chance?
I can't see any useful functions in postgres to make this work.

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear enough, do a step by step manual procedure with your sample data an post also your desired result.

Comment: a table with jsonb as a column.
those jsons have different fields, without strict structure.
i want to make a kv table from them, where key is a name of each field from each json and value is an array of values from jsons where keys are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
create table t1 (data jsonb);
```

Just expand the top-level JSON object into a type record set of key/value pairs, then separate the fields of record by a lateral join then aggregate corresponding values to their keys, like:

```
select j.key, string_agg(j.value, ', ') as value
from t1 t, lateral jsonb_each_text(t.data) j
group by j.key 
order by j.key;
```

Working example [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hSoqaZN1HnmaqrthipGwgj/0) and the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#json_each_text)

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `jsonb_each()` and `jsonb_agg()` to achieve this:

```
select key, jsonb_agg(value) as value
  from some_table
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(data) as e(key, value)
 group by key;
```

If the objective is a `text[]` array, then use `array_agg()`:

```
select key, array_agg(value) as value
  from some_table
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(data) as e(key, value)
 group by key;
```

If you just want a comma-separated string for `value`, then use `string_agg()`:

```
select key, string_agg(value, ',') as value
  from some_table
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(data) as e(key, value)
 group by key;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QKzcdQ_C)